# Where is the history binary file?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I've been looking around for where the "history" binary is located in Linux (Ubuntu), the binary that clears the history list when you type: `history -c`.

I know that I can delete the bash history in `~/.bash_history`, but that doesn't clear the history if you press the up arrow like the `history -c` command will.

I have tried to:

```
$ sudo updatedb
$ locate history
```

but this doesn't come up with the binary.

Comment: To find out how a command is implemented, use `type command`. For example, `type history` prints `history is a shell builtin`. (`type` itself is a shell builtin.)

Answer (score 2):

[`history` is a Bash feature that's built-in to Bash itself](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-History-Builtins).

There is no separate binary, just as there is no binary for `if` or `cd`.

Answer (score 0):

`history` is a shell built-in; it is part of bash itself.